Is My Understanding of C Program Memory Layout Correct? (Text, Data, Heap, Stack Sections)
I'm currently working on an assignment that requires me to analyze the memory layout of a given C program. The task is to identify which parts of the program are stored in different memory sections: code, data, heap, and stack. I need to explain where each variable and function resides in memory when the program is executed. Here’s the code provided by my instructor:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2048

double sum;
double *a;

double dosum(double *x) {
    int i;
    double s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        s += x[i];
    return s;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    a = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    sum = dosum(a);
    printf("sum = %.1f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}

I tried categorizing each part of the code based on conventional memory layout in C programs. Here’s my updated understanding:

Code Section (also known as the .text section): This section contains the compiled binary code for main and dosum functions. I initially referred to this as the "text section" based on other memory layout conventions I encountered, but I understand now that "code section" might be clearer terminology.

Data Section:

Initialized Data: This would contain any global or static variables that are explicitly initialized. Since there are none in this code, this section is empty.
Uninitialized Data (BSS): Holds global variables that are declared but not initialized. In this case, double sum; and double *a; are stored here. I realize now that a is just a pointer declaration and doesn’t imply dynamic allocation itself—only that it can hold the address of dynamically allocated memory.


Heap Section: Stores dynamically allocated memory. Since a is assigned memory using malloc in main, the memory it points to (an array of N doubles) is located in the heap.

Stack Section: Contains function call stack frames, including:

In main: the local variable int i.
In dosum: the parameter double *x and local variables int i and double s.



I made adjustments based on feedback, particularly with the terminology and understanding of pointer declarations. Does this revised analysis more accurately reflect the memory layout for this program?
Thanks in advance for any additional feedback!

Possible misconception: The variable a will eventually point to dynamically allocated memory, but nothing about declaring a pointer means it must point to dynamically allocated memory. Also, if this is C, the result of malloc should not be cast.

@KenWhite Two names for the same thing.  COFF, for example, puts code in the TEXT section.

@asfasfasf https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/7508077

check result of malloc. man malloc

@KenWhite In the elf format the code also often goes into the .text section

@KenWhite I made changes to my forum post:

I changed "Text Section" to "Code Section" to clarify that it contains the compiled binary code.
I clarified my understanding of the pointer a, recognizing that the declaration itself doesn’t imply dynamic allocation—it’s only a storage location for an address, which may point to dynamically allocated memory.

Is this updated understanding correct?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52855674/584518
